# Unable to start unbound service inside of Android JUnit 4 instrumented test

Tags: android, android-testing

I'm trying to test basic unbound service with testing support library framework:
http://developer.android.com/tools/testing-support-library/index.html

LocalService.java:

```
public class LocalService extends Service {
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

LocalServiceTest.java:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class LocalServiceTest {
    @Rule
    public final ServiceTestRule mServiceRule = new ServiceTestRule();

    @Test
    public void testWithUnboundService() throws TimeoutException {
        Intent serviceIntent =
            new Intent(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext(), LocalService.class);

        mServiceRule.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

When I try to run test, I get following TimeoutException:

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Waited for 5 SECONDS, but service was never connected
at android.support.test.rule.ServiceTestRule.waitOnLatch(ServiceTestRule.java:258)
at android.support.test.rule.ServiceTestRule.bindServiceAndWait(ServiceTestRule.java:207)
at android.support.test.rule.ServiceTestRule.startService(ServiceTestRule.java:137)
at com.example.android.testing.ServiceTestRuleSample.LocalServiceTest.testWithBoundService(LocalServiceTest.java:71)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at android.support.test.rule.ServiceTestRule$ServiceStatement.evaluate(ServiceTestRule.java:329)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:54)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:240)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1729)
```

Is it possible to test such kind of services with ServiceTestRule?
If no, is there another appropriate way to start and stop services using JUnit 4 test classes?

Comment: I encountered this same problem. And the solution was to just implement onBind returning a reference to this service.

Comment: Yes, finally I've done it in the same way. Unfortunately, in this case I had to add sleep() to wait for service initialization. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: @PSIXO could you please provide an example of how you return a reference to this service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one

```
@Rule
public final ServiceTestRule mServiceRule = ServiceTestRule.withTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 12):

I met the same issue as you. When I searched the reason in Android reference of [ServiceTestRule](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/ServiceTestRule#startService), I found the reason is so simple.

> Note: This method only supports services that allow clients to bind to
>   them. In other words, if your service onBind(Intent) method returns
>   null then a TimeoutException will be thrown.

Therefore I changed my onBind() method to return a non-null binder.

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent i) {
    return new LocalBinder();
}
```

in which LocalBinder is defined as

```
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    LocalService getService() {
        return LocalService.this;
    }
}
```

Then the TimeoutException went away!

I guess the reason of test failure is that your test runner cannot bind the service under test. **Although the service is running since you have started it in your case, but test runner cannot detect if the service is running.** It has to flag your test case as failed.

Comment: Perfectly explaiined! This should be the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
@Test(timeout=1000 * 60)
public void testWithStartedService(){
    try {
        mServiceRule.startService(
                new Intent(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext(), UpdaterService.class));
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //do something
}
```